# ASP.NET MVC Connect to DSN with limited access

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, odbc, windows-server

I have a database on which I have very limited access. I need to get some data from a VIEW from a database. I have a generic Windows account and I can only login if I Shift+Click on Sql Server Studio and open as different user and use the default Windows Authentication(No Sql Server Authentication Works). I created some DNSs but I can only login with the default Windows NT authentication and SQL Server. The problem is, when I use the Windows NT I get the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
>   'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME'. ERROR [28000]

My Code:

```
try
    {
        OdbcConnection cn;
        OdbcCommand cmd;
        string MyString;
        MyString = "Select * from users";
        cn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=DB77;UID=****;PWD=****;");
        cmd = new OdbcCommand(MyString, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cn.Close();
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
```

I want to use a Windows Authentication to get data from the db. Is it something wrong in Code, ODBC Data Source Admin, IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use NHibernate with MVC. Originally I picked it up because our database doesn't support EF but enjoy it enough that even if we moved to SQL Server I'd keep NHibernate.

The learning curve is kinda weird. It is definitely steep to become an expert, but it is interesting in that it is pretty organic to let it handle more and more of the work for you as you get comfortable with certain layers.

So for your case NHibernate probably supports your database, can be used as a simple data access layer (just returning DTOs), provides a database agnostic interface and can support SQL Server when the time comes. If you end up wanting more out of NHibernate it is there when the time comes.

Comment: And is it able to use a custom windows user and pssword to connect to the db?

Answer (score 0):

nHibernate doesn't have anything to do with Windows Authentication. SQL server will use your process identity to authenticate
if configured to use windows authentication. What that means is that if your application is a web app, you'll need to ensure that your
application runs under the windows identity that can be authenticated by SQL Server.
And it's not possible to provide windows credentials via database connection string, unfortunately.
Example of connection string when using windows authentication:
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Impersonation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx